# ¿Cómo invertir de posición de cada elemento de un array sin cambiar el orden de los elementos?

Tags: java, array, string

buenas noches tengo una tarea y no puedo resolver mi duda y espero me puedan ayudar, lo que tengo es algo similar a esto:

```
String[] cadena = new String[4];
cadena[0] = "hola";
cadena[1] = "mundo";
cadena[2] = "1234";
cadena[3] = "9876";
```

lo que daría esto seria:
'''
[hola, mundo, 1234, 9876]
'''

y lo que quiero que me de como resultado es:
'''
[aloh, odnum, 4321, 6789]
'''

Comment: Lo que tienes que invertir es el string de cada posición del array y no el mismo. Ej. [Invertir string](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/invertir-una-cadena-con-reverse-en-java/). Adicionalmente te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string palabra;    
string cadenaInvertida;

for(int i = 0; i<cadena.length();i++)
{
   palabra = cadena[i];
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(palabra);
   cadenaInvertida = builder.reverse().toString();
   cadena[i] = cadenaInvertida;
}

for(int i=0;i<cadena.length;i++)
{
   System.out.println(cadena[i]);
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es hacer uso de la clase StringBuilder la cual ya implementa el método reverse, entonces utilizamos un ciclo para recorrer el arreglo, entonces cogemos cada elemento del arreglo y le hallamos el inverso, esta palabra inversa la guardamos en el mismo arreglo sobreescribiendo la palabra original, después recorremos con otro ciclo el arreglo e imprimimos las palabras invertidas

Comment: muchas gracias mi estimado, esa fue la solución a mi problema estoy eternamente agradecido